# Why input type text are array in post jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array

I have a form like this

```
    <form id="facform" action="exec/sendfac.php" method="post">
    <input id="mbr_id" class="adresse" name="facdatas[][mbr_id]" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" />
    <input id="nom" class="adresse" name="facdatas[][nom]" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" />
    <input id="adresse" class="adresse" name="facdatas[][adresse]" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input id="ville" class="adresse" name="facdatas[][ville]" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
    <input name="facdatas[][concerne]" class="concern" value="" type="text">
    <input name="ligneFac[][designation]" type="text" class="facBig" />
    <input name="ligneFac[][unite]" type="text" class="facSmall" />
    <input name="ligneFac[][quantite]" type="text" class="facSmall" />
    <input name="ligneFac[][prixUnite]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
    <input name="ligneFac[][taxe]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
    <input name="ligneFac[][totLine]" type="text" class="facSmall" value="" />
    <input id="send" type="submit" name="submit" value="Envoyer" />
```

This form is posted with this jQuery

```
$("#facform").submit(function(e)
{
    var nbr_tr = $('#fac_table tr').length;

    var sendURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var sendPost = $(this).attr("method");
    var facArray = $("#facform").serializeArray();

    $.ajax(
    {
        method: "POST",
        url: sendURL,
        data: facArray,
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            $("#facform").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

and the result give me an array for each text like that:

```
Array ( [facdatas] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [mbr_id] => 26 ) [1] => Array ( [nom] => Gautier Albert ) [2] => Array ( [adresse] => Avenue du Devin du Village 51 ) [3] => Array ( [ville] => 1406 Cronay ) [4] => Array ( [concerne] => TEST ) [5] => Array ( [totalFac] => 69.00 ) ) [ligneFac] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [designation] => Pantalon de training CPNS ) [1] => Array ( [unite] => pièces ) [2] => Array ( [quantite] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [prixUnite] => 69 ) [4] => Array ( [taxe] => 0.00 ) [5] => Array ( [totLine] => 69.00 ) [6] => Array ( [designation] => ) [7] => Array ( [unite] => ) [8] => Array ( [quantite] => ) [9] => Array ( [prixUnite] => ) [10] => Array ( [taxe] => 0.00 ) [11] => Array ( [totLine] => 0.00 ) [12] => Array ( [designation] => ) [13] => Array ( [unite] => ) [14] => Array ( [quantite] => ) [15] => Array ( [prixUnite] => ) [16] => Array ( [taxe] => 0.00 ) [17] => Array ( [totLine] => 0.00 ) [18] => Array ( [designation] => ) [19] => Array ( [unite] => ) [20] => Array ( [quantite] => ) [21] => Array ( [prixUnite] => ) [22] => Array ( [taxe] => 0.00 ) [23] => Array ( [totLine] => 0.00 ) [24] => Array ( [designation] => ) [25] => Array ( [unite] => ) [26] => Array ( [quantite] => ) [27] => Array ( [prixUnite] => ) [28] => Array ( [taxe] => 0.00 ) [29] => Array ( [totLine] => 0.00 ) ) [submit] => Envoyer )
```

It seems that each string is an array and if i would print_r($_POST['data']) it is empty...

2nd question is how to use this array in php without empty rows?

Any idea??

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any data variable therefore its empty.
You can modify the ajax code to

```
$.ajax(
    {
        method: "POST",
        url: sendURL,
        data: {data: facArray},
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            $("#facform").submit();
        }
    });
```

Then you can have $_POST['data'] containing the inputs. Else $_POST will only have all the inputs and not data.

Comment: OK thank you, now I can have my array, but if I use array_filter the result is ever with empty line, do you know how can I remove empty rows?

Comment: Can you explain more please? at which line.

Comment: It is in my exec/sendfac.php

Comment: Now if I add this line in ajax after submit form in the success function
window.location.href = sendURL;
the result is Array() ;
Do you know how?

Comment: here is the code:
print_r(array_filter($_POST['data']));

Comment: If you are satisfied with your original query and solution, you can accept the answer and start this issue in new post/thread. So that you can post the code there as well and can have multiple inputs from multiple users. I will answer there